# Inserting a table with openpyxl

Tags: python, python-2.7, openpyxl

Is there any way with openpyxl (or perhaps another library) to insert a table into an Excel worksheet? By "insert a table", I'm referring to the process outlined [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Quick-start-Create-an-Excel-table-33d08e18-fa0f-40fe-8af3-5683b034ec42), where--in Excel--one would highlight a group of cells, select the Insert tab, and click on the Table icon.

I haven't found any suitable methods in the [worksheet module](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/2.3.3/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html?highlight=worksheet#module-openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet). I also see a [table module](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/openpyxl.styles.table.html), but I can't find any example of how to use it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Openpyxl version 2.4.0 added support for tables.  However, as you noted, [the documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/worksheet_tables.html) for tables thus far does not provide any examples.

Here is a brief example of how to create a table within a worksheet:

```
import openpyxl

# create a new workbook and select the active worksheet
workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
worksheet = workbook.active

# populate some sample data    
worksheet["A1"] = "Fruit"
worksheet["B1"] = "Color"
worksheet["A2"] = "Apple"
worksheet["B2"] = "Red"
worksheet["A3"] = "Banana"
worksheet["B3"] = "Yellow"
worksheet["A4"] = "Coconut"
worksheet["B4"] = "Brown"

# define a table style
mediumStyle = openpyxl.worksheet.table.TableStyleInfo(name='TableStyleMedium2',
                                                      showRowStripes=True)
# create a table
table = openpyxl.worksheet.table.Table(ref='A1:B4',
                                       displayName='FruitColors',
                                       tableStyleInfo=mediumStyle)
# add the table to the worksheet
worksheet.add_table(table)

# save the workbook file
workbook.save('fruit.xlsx')
```

Note: Be sure that you have the latest version of the openpyxl library installed

Comment: Thanks, Dan! I seem to get an error opening the workbooks in Excel after running this. It gives me a `Repaired Records: Table from /xl/tables/table1.xml part (Table)`. Do you get similar results?

Comment: My error was because I was accidentally assigning the same name two different tables. Thanks!

Comment: The documentation now has an example: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/worksheet_tables.html

Answer (score 2):

openpyxl currently does not support table styles. You might want to look at using Xlsxwriter if you need this. See https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/working_with_tables.html

Comment: This answer is now out of date.

Answer (score 2):

It is supported, there's an example in the docs now:

http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/worksheet_tables.html

Make sure you have unique headers (as stated in the docs) and make sure you change the table name from the example: `displayName="Table1" -> displayName="MyTable"`

Comment: Link is broken: did you mean this link https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/worksheet_tables.html ?